# Orthonormality of AOs and MOs in PySCF

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-modeling, quantum-mechanics, pyscf, orbitals

I have a basic question about how to calculate molecular-orbitals from atomic-orbitals in PySCF using the self-consistent field approach. My understanding mathematically is as follows: we start with a set of non-orthonormal atomic-orbitals $\{\phi_i\}$ with overlap matrix $S_{ij} = \langle \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle$. Application of Hartree-Fock produces a new set of orbitals $\{\psi_i\}$ via a unitary orbital transformation $U$. The relationship between the old and new orbitals is:
$$
\psi_i = \sum_j U_{ij} \phi_j.
$$

Since $U$ is unitary, the overlap matrix should be invariant under this transformation, implying that:

$$
\langle \psi_i, \psi_j \rangle = \sum_{kl} U_{ik} U_{jl} S_{kl} = S_{ij}.
$$

However, when I check this, I get that the molecular-orbitals are actually orthonormal, as their overlap matrix is the identity (see below for the code I used), and moreover, the transformation $U$ I obtain is not unitary. My question is: since the self-consistent field method should produce a unitary transformation of the orbitals, what is the approach used to obtain a non-unitary transformation. A follow-up question is: is there a benefit to orthonormalizing the MOs, rather than orthnormalizing the AOs first before obtaining the MOs?

---

````
import numpy as np
from pyscf import gto, scf

mol = gto.M(
    atom='H 0 0 0 ; Li 0 0 1',
    basis='sto-3g'
)

hf = mol.RHF()
hf.scf()
S = hf.get_ovlp()
U = hf.mo_coeff.T # this defines the transformation from AOs to MOs

S_MOs = np.einsum('ik,jl,kl->ij', C, C, S)

# S_MOs is an identity matrix
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solving the Hartree-Fock equations **is** equivalent to unitary rotations of the orbitals, but you are missing the key piece: before Hartree-Fock, the basis set is orthonormalized to produce an orthonormal orbital basis.

In typical programs, this happens by the process of canonical orthonormalization due to Löwdin; see section 7 of the open access review [Molecules 25, 1218 (2020)](https://doi.org/10.3390/molecules25051218). PySCF does not employ this approach by default; instead, it follows an alternative but equivalent approach of solving the generalized eigenvalue problem of the Roothaan equation ${\bf FC} = {\bf SCE}$ with the [eigh function of SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html).

In either case, you will find out that the produced orbital coefficients satisfy ${\bf C}^\text{T} {\bf SC} = {\bf 1}$,  that is, the orbital coefficients are orthonormal in the overlap metric. Note that ${\bf C}^\text{T} {\bf C} \neq {\bf 1}$ except in the case of an orthonormal basis, $ {\bf S} = {\bf 1}$,